# Webflux: OnErrorResume after repeats are exhausted is not being triggered

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor, reactive-streams

I am trying to execute the code after repeat exhaustion using `onErrorResume` but onErrorResume is not being trigger.

Here is the code sample

```java
Mono.just(request)
                .filter(this::isConditionSatified)
                .map(aBoolean -> performSomeOperationIfConditionIsSatified(request))
                .repeatWhenEmpty(Repeat.onlyIf(i -> true)
                        .exponentialBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(5)), Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))
                .delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
                    log.warn("Max timeout reached", throwable);
                    return Mono.just(false);
                });
```

`onErrorResume` is never trigged. I am trying to use it as a fallback. My goal is if the repeat exhaustion is hit, return the `false` value.

My unit test complains of

```
expectation "expectNext(false)" failed (expected: onNext(false); actual: onComplete())
```

Any help or suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: I tried .defaultIfEmpty(false) and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since an `empty` source is valid by itself, `repeatWhenEmpty` doesn't necessarily propagate an exception after exhausting its attempts. The `Repeat` util from addons doesn't, even when the "timeout" triggers (as hinted in the `timeout` parameter's javadoc: "timeout after which no new repeats are initiated", ok that could be clearer).

since you're using `repeatWhenEMPTY`, I'm guessing that the empty case is always "irrelevant" to you and thus `defaultIfEmpty(false)` should be the acceptable solution.

Comment: thank you for explaining. Yes, `.defaultIfEmpty` worked. Right, empty case is always "irrelevant". Right, I was under the assumption would be thrown. Thank you